# Whatsapp chat api limit for contact list

Tags: php, whatsapp

I want to know what is the contact list limit for Whatsapp chat api using php.
Here I attached the github link: https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API. If there is limit for contact list, how I can bypass the Contact list limit.